# Does ANT apply prefixValues if there is no property of the desired name ? Or is this a bug ? (SSCCE provided)

Tags: ant, properties, prefix

I have this weird behavior with `ant` and properties and I'd like to know what do you think. I don't get the logic.
This behavior could be usefull but I would like to know if I can rely on it or if this is a bug.

It looks like ant is applying the prefix when expanding the right hand side of properties if there is no property of the desired name. Here is the SSCCE:

build.properties:

```
a=A
formula=${a}
```

build.xml:

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <property name="test.a" value="[test.a has been used instead of a, why? prefixValues is false]" />
        <property file="build.properties" prefix="test" prefixValues="false" />
        <echo>${test.formula}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

output:

```
test:
    [echo] [test.a has been used instead of a, why? prefixValues is false]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 364 milliseconds
```

As you can see, test.formula should use "a" and not "test.a" but "a" is never defined. Is it the reason?

Comment: +1 I've tested this and I can say that this is strange.

Comment: Here's the original enhancement request, if it helps: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some more test and could get a lot of different results.

After checking the sources, I think that there is a bug when looking for properties while adding them through a file. By modifying some ant source code, I could get it to work.

In the end, I decided to fill a bug report (https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54769) with a proposed patch.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it seems weird.
In my opinion, the output should be `${a}`

I did a few test and I notice that:

If you define `a` in the `build.xml` instead of `build.properties` : it works as expected. i.e. with the following `build.xml`:

```
<project default="test">
<target name="test">
    <property name="a" value="A" />
    <property file="build.properties" prefix="test" prefixValues="false" />
    <echo>${test.formula}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

and the build.properties

```
formula=${a}
```

output is

```
A
```

**But**, if you change to `prefixValues="true"` the ouput is :

```
${a}
```

while I was expecting : `${test.a}`

Finally, if you define `<property name="test.a" value="some value" />` in the build.xml (always with `prefixValues="true"`) : the output is now (as expected)

```
some value
```

So, my conclusion:

- prefixValues works fine as soon as the property used on the *right side* is not defined in the same property file.
- prefixValues is ignored for properties used on the *right side* and defined in the same property file.

Comment: I'm not sure if your conclusion are complete. I did some more tests and got all sorts of output. In the end, it really lookks like there is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look in Ant code, in properties related classes, on `org.apache.tools.ant.property.ResolvePropertyMap` class:

```
public void resolveAllProperties(Map<String, Object> map, String prefix,
                                     boolean prefixValues) {
        // The map, prefix and prefixValues flag get used in the
        // getProperty callback
        this.map = map;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.prefixValues = prefixValues;

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            expandingLHS = true;
            Object result = getProperty(key);
            String value = result == null ? "" : result.toString();
            map.put(key, value);
        }
```

Then, in `getProperty(String)` method (snippet):

```
            // If the property we are looking up is a key in the map
            // (first call into this method from resolveAllProperties)
            // or we've been asked to prefix the value side (later
            // recursive calls via the GetProperty interface) the
            // prefix must be prepended when looking up the property
            // outside of the map.
            String fullKey = name;
            if (prefix != null && (expandingLHS || prefixValues)) {
                fullKey = prefix + name;
            }
```

So, as you can see, if the property is present in the property file, it will receive the prefix even if `prefixValues` is false.

Comment: The issue is about the value, though, right?  So that's when `expandingLHS` is false.  So only when `prefixValues` is true would it enter the if block for the "value side" of the property.

Comment: Sorry, @whiskeyspider, I didn't understand your comment (perhaps because English is not my native language)

Comment: As @whiskeyspider said, I think that the portion of code you are providing is not the real issue. 'ExpandingLHS' should be responsible of the name of the properties, not their value. Still, you point something interesting and I decided to have a closer look at ant source code.

Answer (score -1):

It's because properties are immutable.  Once set, they're stuck that way for the rest of the build.  [Check out the docs for 'property' on the Ant manual.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)  It's actually kind of a problem for some people, so the [ant-contrib guys included a new  task to mimic a variable.](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)

If you change your build around like this:

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <property file="build.properties" prefix="test" prefixValues="false" />
        <property name="test.a" value="[test.a has been used instead of a, why? prefixValues is false]" />
        <echo>${test.formula}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

You get 'A' on the console.  This is because test.a and test.formula got defined in the first call to  before your new (ignored) assignment to 'test.a'

Comment: The issue is that `test.formula` should equal the value of property `a` not `test.a`.  Since `prefixValues` is false, the OP is expecting that it should print literally "${a}".

Comment: @David I am aware of immutability of properties but that is not the issue. I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. I'll try to make it better.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're getting at.  After a little more testing, it looks like 'prefixValues' is basically ignored.